# Why doesn't my donut chart, created with Chart.js, appear?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, donut-chart

I have created some charts with Chart.js and they are on my website [http://projetoplenario.com/proposicoes.html]. I tried to insert the same chart on other html page of my website, but it doesn't work.

Let's consider, for example, the first chart of proposicoes.html. It's named "reformaTrabalhistaChart". On reformaTrabalhista.html [http://projetoplenario.com/reformaTrabalhista.html] there is also that code to insert the chart.

But, I don't know why, it doesn't work on reformaTrabalhista.html and does work on proposicoes.html.

How can I insert the same chart on reformaTrabalhista.html?

```html
<div class="boxChart">
  <a href="reformaTrabalhista.html">
    <canvas id="reformaTrabalhistaChart"></canvas>
  </a>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="boxChart">
  <canvas id="reformaTrabalhistaChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

```js
var reformaTrabalhistaChart;
var data = [
  {
    value: 50,
    color: "green"
  }, {
    value: 26,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    value: 1,
    color: "orange"
  }, {
    value: 1,
    color: "purple"
  }, {
    value: 3,
    color: "gray"
  }
];

var options = {
  animation: true,
  animationEasing: 'easeInOutQuart',
  animationSteps: 80
};

//Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("reformaTrabalhistaChart")
                  .getContext("2d");

reformaTrabalhistaChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I've just included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, you are trying to get other canvas elements, which are not present in **reformaTrabalhista.html**.

You should better get canvas­*'s* context, for all the canvases, like so :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-id-here");
var ctx = canvas && canvas.getContext("2d");
```

and define the chart instance, as such :

```
chart-variable-name = ctx && new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);
```

Here is the modified version of **`mycharts.js`** - https://kopy.io/0HiRj